# Verbs that describe user Do's and Don'ts

Tags: word-usage, verbs

A lot of websites have code of conduct that describe user do's and don'ts. For example:

"Stack Exchange <*verb1*> users to post relevant and constructive answers and <*verb2*> users to post off-topic discussions."

In this context, what should be appropriate for *verb1* and *verb2*? I have come up with the following candidates but none of them seems right:

verb1: enforces, verb2: forbid  (These verbs seem too serious)

verb1: recommends, verb2: discourages

Comment: These "Do's and Don'ts" are not always of the same kind. Most times they are recommendatory, sometimes mandatory, but most often they are guidelines. So I don't think it's possible to fit one term for all cases.

Comment: Another pair is *prescribes* and *proscribes*. (Also, a pet peeve: if you're going to put an apostrophe before one word's *s*, I would put it before the other word's *s* too. So, either *Dos and Don'ts* or *Do's and Don't's*. Even though I know people are consistently inconsistent with this . . .)

Comment: Of possible interest: Many of the internet's technical underpinnings grew out of an on-going series of _Requests for Comments_ (RFCs). These developed a set of words/phrases (e.g. "_MUST_", "_SHOULD NOT_" etc.) to describe compulsory, forbidden or advisory behaviour, which are codified in [RFC 2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with **encourages** and **discourages**. While those don't necessarily present as "musts", as in technically you can fail to receive the encouragement/discouragement, the point still comes across. It's similar to your second suggestion.

Requires and forbids are also useful, but you found forbids to be too serious; perhaps **requires** and **disallows**.

"must" and "must not" also achieve similar purposes, though they are adverbs. However, the word order would need to be changed:

> "Stack Exchange users **must** post relevant and constructive answers and **must not** post off-topic discussions."